# How to hide minimap like vertical bar on the right of VSCode editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make the editing space as wide as possible because I open two tabs side by side.

First I remove the vertical scroll bar.

```json
{
    "editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden",
}
```

And now I don't know how to remove the right bar below. It is like  minimap but `"editor.minimap.enabled": false` does not remove it.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also settings that you might want to use:

```json
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true,
"editor.overviewRulerBorder": false,
```

There will still be some things showing there on the right, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 0,
```

It sets the scroll bar size to 0, so the scroll bar is fully removed